# Existence of divisors in a finite set.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Is it true that however we pick 1011 numbers alongside of $\{1,2,...,2020\}$ then for at least two of them we'll have that one of those two numbers is a divisor of the other?

Meaning that however we pick $A\subseteq ${$1,2,...,2020$} with $|A|=1011$, then $\exists x,y\in A$ s.t. $x|y$ or $y|x$.

What I thought of is somehow using the Pidgeonhole principle, but I've no constructive thoughts from that on. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: HINT: Consider the $1010$ pairs $\{n,2n\}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,1010$.

Answer (score 1):

Every integer is a power of two times an odd number. There are only 1010 candidates for the odd part. Apply pigeon hole